# Strong Semaphore Queuing Discipline and Starvation

Tags: algorithm, queue, semaphore

In William Stallings' book on Operating Systems, he defines a **strong semaphore** as one that has a FIFO queuing discipline, and a **weak semaphore** one that is unordered. Surely there are other queuing disciplines for strong semaphores, such as by priority? Or would this no longer be a strong semaphore, since starvation would become possible? (Stallings says that strong semaphores do not allow for starvation.) Is the primary distinction between strong and weak ordered/unordered, or starvation possible/impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to the literature on semaphores, I have never seen (with my limited knowledge) anyone using FIFO or some form of ordering as the criteria for weak/strong categorization. In fact, starvation-freedom is not always the criteria either. The initial literatures (due to viz. *Morris('79)*, *Martin and J. R. Burch('85)*, *Udding('86)*, *Friedberg and Peterson('87)*, and *Haldar and Subramanian('88)*) used certain characteristics of **‘P’** and **‘V’** operations to define weak-semaphore. Interestingly, all of the definitions from the cited researchers eventually imply possible presence of starvation in case of weak semaphores. Further, though FIFO guarantees starvation-freedom, referring to the term FIFO or some form of ordering, in my opinion, restricts the behavior of the semaphore. One form of restriction could be that, for example, a FIFO ordering would imply that a semaphore has some kind of buffer attached to it in order to keep track of the blocked processes/threads on the **‘P’** operation. For hardware implementation of semaphores, this definition might be too restrictive. Another form of restrictions could be that instead of considering all possible ordering schemes with same bounded overtaking by *k* (i.e. no process will be overtaken more than *k* times), one would be restricted to consider each scheme as one different kind of semaphore. Thus, my personal opinion is to define a weak-semaphore as one that does NOT guarantee starvation-freedom (but guarantees dead-lock-freedom). However, if you’re more deep into research-grade activities, then by all means feel free to use more mathematical or/and fine-grained definitions as you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, one non-FIFO non-starving possibility (among many) is to select the next process in a round-robin manner. For example, if the order is 1, 2, 3, 4, and while 1 is holding the semaphore, 4 and then 3 request it, then the next process up is 3. No process P starves because, after each request of P, each other process has at most one critical section before P's request is granted.

Definitions of "strong semaphore" in the first pages of hits from Google are split between "no starvation" and "FIFO". Which one is "right" is a matter of taste – given this mess (and the general overuse of strong as an adjective in mathematical writing), I'd probably use neither.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no starvation with a priority queue with a predefined priority on queue elements. As you can see it's just a regular queue except the next element has the highest priority. So if you implement priorities with FIFO logic (first in has the highest priority) there will be no starvation. Otherwise it can cause starvation.

Comment: but then it would just degenerate to a normal queue with a slightly more complex implementation..

Comment: I just found that [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) says, "When processes have different priorities the queue may be ordered by priority, so that the highest priority process is taken from the queue first." The question remains, though, how this relates to the terms *strong* and *weak*.

Comment: It depends on implementation.. Starling definition of "strong" is no starvation as you indicate. If we use FIFO for implementing we always sure that new items on last, so let say 5 items on queque, we are sure that all of them will be stay in equally.. But if it's priority queque they'll have some priority numbers.. Some of them will be more important.. Maybe new incoming elements of semaphore queque always have higher priority then some alredy in queque.. So old items have no chance in this case which causes starvation..

Comment: btw i mean William Stalling not Starling :)